# Image blind separation

Tags: noise, ica

I am working in image cryptography using an ICA algorithm like JADE. To evaluate my work, I am used the SDR and PSNR.

I would like to know what the acceptable values of the SDR and PSNR in image blind separation are.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to compare your method to others is to run the algorithms on a common data set. Quntative measures such as PSNR vary significantly across images.

It is also important to consider subjective analysis. After all, your research is aiming for improvements in **appearance**.